# Must I submit the update to my app via Xcode 4 Archive Sharing feature before or after I entered meta data in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, app-store

This is a bit confusing, so maybe someone can help get the right order. First create all the meta data for the update and then submit the binary - or first submit the binary and then edit the meta data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create all the meta data for the update and then submit the binary.

After entering the meta data, the submission (app/update) will reach the status: Waiting for Upload. Now you can upload the actual binary.